# Error on heroku but on local with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am creating a Blog app. This is working well on local, but on Hroku, when I tried to post comments, `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` appeared.

On local, I can posts comments on each article.

I use sqLite3 for local, and postgre for heroku.

**Error log**

```
2019-03-25T07:15:44.567261+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.567194 #4] DEBUG -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242]   [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-03-25T07:15:44.569317+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.569236 #4] DEBUG -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242]   [1m[36mArticle Load (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (2) LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-03-25T07:15:44.569537+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.569468 #4]  INFO -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570193+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.570137 #4] FATAL -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242]   
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570287+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.570226 #4] FATAL -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570292+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (2) LIMIT $1
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570294+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                     ^
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570296+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (2) LIMIT $1):
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570339+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.570285 #4] FATAL -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242]   
2019-03-25T07:15:44.570427+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-25T07:15:44.570372 #4] FATAL -- : [ff69042f-aa16-4d59-8905-8b5beacee242] app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

**timestamp_create_comments.rb**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :article, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tested your app on production mode?

Comment: This is a bad idea: "I use sqLite3 for local, and postgre for heroku". You need to develop, test, and deploy with the same database. Install PostgreSQL in your development and test environments, then find where in your code you say something like `Article.where(id)`, `Article.find_by(id)`, or similar.

Comment: What does your controller look like?